# How to animate the objects in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using UIImageViews. I'd like this behaviour: if we touch the UIImageView it needs to zoom double and if the user remove his finger set the UIImageView to the actual position of the finger... How can I do?

Can any one please tell me the code for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

U can use UIScrollView for this, with UIImageView as a sub-view of the scroll view.

For this, U need to sub-class UIScrollView to write a custom scroll view.
It will have all the properties of UIScrollView. Only thing, U have to override touchesEnded: method, which will notify the superview. So in the superview, again u can set the zoomscale to 1, to make it to actual position.

Answer (score 0):

implement the delegate methods  `touchesBegan:withEvent:`  and `– touchesEnded:withEvent:`

in touches began method change the frame of the imageview to double the size of the `imageview` and in `touchesEnded` change the frame to the original size.

while declaring the image enable user interaction on it

```
 UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
imageview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
imageview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
}
```

TNX